# How can i display popup box using react-native-router-flux

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I am trying to display popup view when user touches something element. i am using react-native-router-flux for navigation. i tried using their modal property or scheme=popup etc., but i am not able to get it working as popup. same component works as navigation. can you please help.

Answer (score 2):

i made a mistake in setting things up. Looks like the root component scene and modal component scene has to be at same level and not modal as child of root.
like

```
<Scene key="modal" component={Modal}>
    <Scene key="root" component={Base}>
        <Scene key="some" component={Some} />
    </Scene>
    <Scene key="actualModal" component={ActualModal} />
</Scene>
```

Comment: Can you pls provide the actual code to show the popup ?